# Proving that an infinitely rapidly oscillating integral is always zero.

Tags: integration, limits, proof-writing

I have the following problem: suppose $f (q)$ is a continuous function. Prove that:
\begin{align}
   \lim_{c \rightarrow \infty }    \int^{\infty}_{0} d q f (q) e^{ i q c }   =0
\end{align}
Intuitively the following statement seems to be very logical (with this limit one can always make the oscillation so rapid that the increase of f(q) during one oscillation goes to zero and cancellation happens), however since I have not much experience with formal mathematical proofs I have no idea how to properly show why this holds. Perhaps some type of delta epsilon reasoning can be used where the integral is divided in infinitesimal cancelling slices?

Comment: This is the Riemann Lebesgue lemma.  See the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Lebesgue_lemma).  The conventional proof works for a wider class of functions than simply those that are continuous, but they must be integrable on  the relevant interval, and the proof is correspondingly more advanced.

Comment: This is false, for consider the continuous function $f(q)=e^{-iqc}.$

Comment: @Allawonder Well, that's not allowed I think, since that would make f(q) dependent on c which does not have a specific value but goes to infinity

Comment: @ZachJacobs $f(q)$ is very well defined for any $c.$ Or if you claim otherwise, then for the very same reason your integrand is also not defined. I think your function $f(q)$ has to be integrable over $(0,+\infty).$ Check the statement of the theorem again.

Comment: @Allawonder Isn't a variable for which I take the limit to infinity by definition not well defined? Infinity is not really well defined, I can fix a certain very large value for c and make a "copy" of it to use for my f as you propose but by the virtue of that the original c goes to infinity I can take my original c to be even larger than that, so that again the cancellation happens.

Comment: @ZachJacobs I don't really understand what you're trying to say. But my point is that your integrand is uniquely defined for all values of $c.$ Also, your integrand is defined for all values of $c$ if and only if my counterexample for $f(q)$ is defined for all values of $c.$

Comment: @Allawonder ... The point is that $f(q)$ is a function of the variable $q$, and $f$ is independent of the variable $c$.  This independence is required, as shown by the counterexample $e^{-iqc}$.

Comment: @Allawonder yes I agree it is uniquely defined for all values. However, when you consider the continuous function you proposed you will always have to fix c, i.e. take to be very large and make a copy of it. It won't be the real c because there is no real c, it is something that goes to infinity. If you were to say: no I want my f (q) to really be dependent on c which I take to infinity, then sure it will be non-zero, however that is a fundamentally different integral because then f(q) is not a fixed function but depends on a c for which you take the limit to infinity.